# How to convert a word to audio in windows 8 metro app deveopment?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing one Windows 8 metro app (for kids)where I need to pronounce the english word that user enters .Is there any API for this ?I am using HTML5 and javascript for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are no (TTS) Text-to-Speech API provided for Metro apps. You need to implement a cloud based API for that.
Try [speak.js](http://nikos-web-development.netai.net/blog/text-to-speech-in-html5-and-javascript/) which is a JavaScript port of [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I like the Google TTS API better.

Comment: But can i have speak.js API added to my project so that I don't need to depend on the internet connection for metro app to play the text?

Comment: There is no offline-solution at the moment. You will have to develop it yourself, or use the cloud version. One implementation of cloud TTS is given [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pavanpareta/text-to-speech-in-windows-phone-7/).